# How do I go about installing a Linux service for OTA update of Android image

Tags: android, ubuntu-server, ota

We have a Chinese partner that provides us with hardware and occasional software updates.

For OTA (over the air) updates, they think we are best off providing the service from one of our servers.

I do not have any experience for this type of thing and I am wondering if anyone has some tips on how to go about this.

Our Linux servers are of the Ubuntu variety.

I am sure to get some information from our partners, but I hoped to gain some information beforehand, hence my posting this question